# More than one 'Open xxxxx here as Administrator'

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd.exe, runas

I want the option to open a Command window or Powershell window as Administrator from the drive and directory context menus in Windows.

I can have *either* by creating and populating the special 'runas' registry keys shown below, but is there a way I can have *both* listed on the context menu and have *both* run as Administrator?

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas]
...
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\runas\command]
...
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
...
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
...
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas]
...
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\runas\command]
...
```

Comment: Well afaik the "runas" in all those paths is just a subkey and has no speacial meaning. The meaning comes from the command. All subkeys under shell are interpreted, so if you just create one named runas for powershell and one named runas2 for cmd it should work.

Comment: @Syberdoor some keynames under `shell` like `run`, `open`, `print`, `runas` etc. etc. _have_ speacial meaning having something to do with [IContextMenu::InvokeCommand method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776096(v=vs.85).aspx) or [ShellExecute function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx). Insufficient battlespace here to explain it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Next registry hack works for directories on Windows 8.1:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas]
"HasLUAShield"=""
@="CMD here as administrator"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runas\command]
@="cmd.exe /S /K pushd \"%V\""
"DelegateExecute"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell]
"HasLUAShield"=""
@="PowerShell here as administrator"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\runasPowerShell\command]
@="Powershell Start-Process PowerShell -verb runas -ArgumentList '-noexit', 'Push-Location -literalPath ''\"%V\"'''"
"DelegateExecute"=""
```

You could add analogous `runas` and `runasPowerShell` subkeys for drives under the `[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell]` as well.

[image: Run both CMD and PowerShell with elevated privileges]